# ReactJs: Как в переменную передать стиль для печати?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, print

Как в переменную передать стиль для печати?

---

У меня есть переменная:

```
const styles = {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
                height: '7px',
                width: '100%',
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0,
                cursor: 'row-resize'
            };
```

Как можно задать стиль на случай печати?

Что то в таком роде:

```
const styles = {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
                height: '7px',
                width: '100%',
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0,
                cursor: 'row-resize',
                '@media print': {
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }
            };
```

---

Заранее Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Подскажите, а в чём конкретно сложность? Вы хотите добавить в styles строчку                 '@media print': {
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }? Или как заменить стиль в html?

Comment: Да именно, хочу добавить медия принт, мой вариант не работает при печати.